# Problems with the BITMAPFILEHEADER

Tags: c++, winapi, bmp

I just started to learn more about the .bmp file format and wrote a small C++ programm.

Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
FILE* imageFile;
fopen_s (&imageFile, this->GetImagePath (), "rb");

fread (&this->bmfh, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, imageFile);    
std::cout << bmfh.bfSize << " " << bmfh.bfOffBits << " " << std::endl;
```

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183374%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `bmfh.bfSize` should return the size of the bitmap file.

But in my case `bmfh.bfOffBits` (54) is higher than `bmfh.bfSize` (14)? What could be the reason?
Because my idea was to allocate memory for the image data in this way:

```
this->size = bmfh.bfSize - bmfh.bfOffBits;
pixelData = new BYTE[this->size];
```

Comment: bmfh is a class variable:
BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfh;

Comment: are you sure you're reading proper BMP? (the bfType should be 19778)

Comment: I checked the bfType and it is 19778

Comment: there are different versions of that struct. How are you working out which one you have encountered?

Comment: I'm using the struct defined in windows.h
Is this my mistake?

Comment: Solved my Problem. bfSize is the size of the struct not of the file itself :/

Answer (score 1):

bmfh.bfOffBits (54) - is the size from the start of the file to the actual RGB data of the bmp file. This is usually equal to 54.

That is, from offset 0 (from start of file) to offset 53 is the header of the bmp file. So that from offset 54 onwards is the actual RGB pixel data of the image file.

bmfh.bfSize (14) - is the actual size of the image.

I try googling on this matter and this is the best source I've found.

http://www.fortunecity.com/skyscraper/windows/364/bmpffrmt.html

Comment: Thank you for your Research.

But is it possible that the bmfh.bfSize is smaller then the bmfh.bfOffBits? 

According to your link bmfh.bfSize contains the the size of the file in bytes.

And according to the microsoft documentation bmfh.bfOffBits specifies the offset in bytes.

Comment: Solved my Problem.
bfSize is the size of the struct not of the file itself :/